# Instantiate object from list c#

Tags: c#, list, arraylist, random

I'm a beginner in programming with C#, and I'm trying Unity.

When I try to instantiate a `gameObject` random from an array list(list), but I have a error (The tape object cannot be used as tope parapete T. )and I don't find the solution.

I have 6 gameobjects:

```
public gameobject Red;
public gameobject yellow;
etc...
```

to 6.

y cont have a arraylist dynamic for add or remote object. Like this:

```
public ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

Then, I add the gameobjects:

```
list.Add (Red);
list.Add(Yellow);
```

And to finish, I instantiate random objects from arraylist (sometimes different number of objects )

```
color = Instantiate(list[random.range(0, list.Length)]);
```

But not found, and have this error:

> The tape object cannot be used as tope parapete T.

Comment: To start with I think it might help to not use `ArrayList`, but instead `List<gameobject>`. This would mean that you're using a strongly-typed list and this may solve at least some of your troubles for you.

Comment: You also should show us the code for the `Instantiate` method.

Answer (score 1):

It's a question about picking a random item from a list. Let me propose to use a `List<T>` instead of an `ArrayList`. Here an example:

```
static void Main()
{
    var Red = new GameObject();
    var Yellow = new GameObject();

    List<GameObject> gameObjects = new List<GameObject>() { Red, Yellow };
    var randomGameObject = gameObjects[(new Random()).Next(gameObjects.Count)];

    // color = Instantiate(randomGameObject)

    //Console.WriteLine(randomGameObject);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Instantiate` method is probably declared like this:

```
Color Instantiate(GameObject gameObject)
{
    // ...
}
```

But `ArrayList` is not strongly typed, i.e. it returns items of `object` type. Therefore you must cast the items to `GameObject`:

```
color = Instantiate((GameObject)list[random.range(0, list.Length)]);
```

But a better solution is to use a strongly typed generic list `List<GameObject>`. It works much like `ArrayList` but returns items typed as `GameObject`.

```
public List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>();
list.Add(Red);
list.Add(Yellow);

color = Instantiate(list[random.range(0, list.Count)]);
```

Comment: Explained better but I find that you are tolerant about the use of the ArrayList, In your place  I dont propose a solution using ArrayList

Comment: I don't propose a solution with `ArrayList`. I show how the existing solution using `ArrayList` could be fixed and suggest using a `List<GameObject>` instead as a better solution.